# OpenCV4android - Configure SVM's training with the same params as Weka's SMO

Tags: android, opencv, weka, svm

I've tested a dataset in Weka's 3.6.9 [SMO](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html) (didn't change anything, just used the standard params) and got great results. I tried to configure the same SMO in OpenCV's [SVM](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html) (for Android) but I'm not getting good results. I would like to configure and train the OpenCV's SVM in my app the same way as the standard SMO found in Weka, could someone help me?

**Weka's standard SMO** configuration (with 10 fold cross-validation):

```
weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -C 250007 -E 1.0"
```

The polynomial kernel (in Weka SMO) is as follows: **K(x, y) = (x, y)^p** or **K(x, y) = ((x, y)+1)^p**, with p = 1.

The formula in OpenCV's documentation for polykernel is as follows:
 **K(x,y) = (*gamma**(x,y)+*coef0*)^*degree***, with *gamma* > 0.

Now my code trying to configure the same way in **OpenCV4Android:**

```
CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
    params.set_svm_type(CvSVM.C_SVC);
    params.set_kernel_type(CvSVM.POLY);
    params.set_C(1.0);
    params.set_degree(1.0);
    params.set_coef0(0.0);
    params.set_gamma(1.0);
    params.set_term_crit(new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS, 10000, 1e-12));

    CvSVM svm = new CvSVM();

    // n-fold cross validation
    int kFolds = 10;

    CvParamGrid C = new CvParamGrid();
    CvParamGrid p = new CvParamGrid();
    CvParamGrid nu = new CvParamGrid();

    CvParamGrid gamma = new CvParamGrid();
    gamma.set_step(0.0);
    CvParamGrid coeff = new CvParamGrid();
    CvParamGrid degree = new CvParamGrid();

    svm.train_auto(trainData, responses, new Mat(), new Mat(), params,
            kFolds, C, gamma, p, nu, coeff, degree, false);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `p=1` you are basically using a linear kernel. It's better to move away from polynomial in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the default settings for Weka's SMO found here http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html

Looking at your code,

> params.set_coef0(1.0);

should do the trick.

In more detail, to make LibSVM (or any library based on it such as openCV MLL) produce identical result you want the following settings for your kernel:

You should be using C-SVC (default), so no changes there.
kernel: polykernel instead of rbf

notice how SMO and LibSVM differ in that LibSVM's polykernel is (gamma+coefficient)^exp (or something like that) while SMO has ( + 1)^exp.

Therefore, it is clear you need the following settings:
exponent: 1
gamma: 1.0 
coefficient: 1.0

I ran a couple of test and this was sufficient. If not, you may want to adjust other settings, as well, to match the defaults.